# Creating Primary Keys

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know which column should I put in the PK first, [ID_CHECK] or [ID_CONTROL].

```
   CREATE TABLE QUALITY_CONTROL
(
    [ID_CHECK] [int] NULL,
    [ID_CONTROL] [int] NOT NULL

)

 ALTER TABLE QUALITY_CONTROL  ADD CONSTRAINT QUALITY_CONTROL_P01 PRIMARY KEY ([ID_CHECK], [ID_CONTROL])
```

or

```
  ALTER TABLE QUALITY_CONTROL
 ADD CONSTRAINT QUALITY_CONTROL_P01 PRIMARY KEY ([ID_CONTROL], [ID_CHECK])
```

The [ID_CHECK] column has more repeated data, I don't know if that means anything.

Thanks.

Comment: How is the data entered?  How is it commonly queried?  IE is `select * from quality_control where id_check = @someid` a common query pattern?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

I really don't know how to answer any of the questions, you could tell me the basic points.

Thanks.

Comment: If ID_CHECK has more repeated data, a primary key starting with it will be less effective, but if ID_CONTROL is rarely used to identify (in `JOIN`'s `ON` conditions or `WHERE` conditions) or order (with `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` clauses) the data  then starting the PK on it would be almost pointless. If ID_CONTROL is less repeated and more frequently referenced, it would almost certainly be the best to start the key with. Without knowing the typical usage, we're basically just guessing.

Comment: This won't work at all since `ID_CHECK` allows `NULL` and can't therefore be part of a `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: @BillTür I'm sorry, I put it wrong, it's [ID CHECK] [int] NOT NULL

Comment: I understood, for now I appreciate the tips, they were very useful, I will check with the development team.
thanks.